# javascript/lodash: cleaner way to spread properties?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a piece of data below.  It's an object that contains 2 nested objects with arrays nested in those:

```
let data = {
    obj1: {
       names: ['joe'],
       ages: false,
    },
    obj2: {
       names: ['james'],
       ages: true,
    },
}
```

I want to return:

```
 {
   names: ['james','joe'],
   ages: true,
 }
```

Right now, I am doing this with:

```
  const foo = Object.entries(data)[0][1] ?? [];
  const foo2 = Object.entries(data)?.[1]?.[1] ?? [];

  const finalData = {...foo, ...foo2 }
```

how can I clean that up using loDash's groupBy?

Comment: Why `ages: true`?

Comment: it's just a boolean value.  The 2nd object's value  of `ages` should always overwrite the first.

Comment: How do you define "second"? Are you really going to rely on the order of object properties? If order is important, you should really be using an array...

Answer (score 1):

Use `_.values()` to get the two sub-objects, and then merge them using `_.mergeWith()`. If the values are an array, concat them, if not let `_.mergeWith()` handle the merge by returning `undefined`:

```js
const data = {
    obj1: {
       names: ['joe', 'james'],
       ages: false,
    },
    obj2: {
       names: ['james'],
       ages: true,
    },
}

const result = _.mergeWith(
  {}, ..._.values(data),
  (a, b) => _.isArray(a) ? _.uniq([...a, ...b]) : undefined
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: wouldn't this duplicate the data rather than merge?  if each object has `names: ['joe'],` you'd end up with `['joe', 'joe']`

Comment: If you also want to dedupe, use the uniq function. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: ok, that would be great to see whenever you can.  Thanks!

Comment: The answer is updated. You can see that 'james` appear on both objects.